# boost::asio io_service doesn't return after stop()

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm working on an application that uses boost::asio to listen on different ports for TCP and UDP packets. I did this by using similar server classes as in the asio tutorial examples and I point them all to a single io_service.

So overall my main function (win32 console application) looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //some initializations here

    try
    {
        asio::io_service io_service;
        TcpServer ServerTCP_1(io_service, /*port number here*/);
        TcpServer ServerTCP_2(io_service, /*port number here*/);
        UdpServer ServerUDP(io_service, /*port number here*/);

        io_service.run();
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    //cleanup code here

    return 0;
}
```

I also read through the HTTP server example where a `signal_set` is used for performing an asynchronous operation that gets activated when the quit signal comes in (which I also implemented in the server class).

Here is my `TcpServer` class:

```
class TcpServer : private noncopyable
{
public:
    TcpServer(asio::io_service& io_service, int port) : 
        acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)), 
        signals_(io_service), context_(asio::ssl::context::sslv3)
    {
        SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(context_.native_handle(), "ALL");
        SSL_CTX_set_options(context_.native_handle(), SSL_OP_ALL);
        SSL_CTX_use_certificate_ASN1(context_.native_handle(), sizeof(SSL_CERT_X509), SSL_CERT_X509);
        SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_ASN1(EVP_PKEY_RSA, context_.native_handle(), SSL_CERT_RSA, sizeof(SSL_CERT_RSA));
        SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(context_.native_handle(), 1);

        signals_.add(SIGINT);
        signals_.add(SIGTERM);
        signals_.add(SIGBREAK);
#if defined(SIGQUIT)
        signals_.add(SIGQUIT);
#endif // defined(SIGQUIT)
        signals_.async_wait(boost::bind(&TcpServer::handle_stop, this));

        start_accept();
    }

private:
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    asio::ssl::context context_;
    asio::signal_set signals_;
    TcpConnection::pointer new_ssl_connection;

    void start_accept(){
        new_ssl_connection.reset(new TcpConnection(acceptor_.get_io_service(), context_));
        acceptor_.async_accept( new_ssl_connection->socket(), 
                                    boost::bind(&TcpServer::handle_acceptSSL, this, asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void handle_acceptSSL(const system::error_code& error){
        if(!error)
            new_ssl_connection->start();
        start_accept();
    }
    void handle_stop(){
        acceptor_.close();
        printf("acceptor closed");
    }
};
```

Now since I have 3 different server objects he should close all acceptors of them leaving the `io_service` without work which again causes the `io_service` to return from the `run()` call which should make the program get to the cleanup code in the main function, right?
And besides all that the `printf` call should be executed 3 times as well or?

Well first of all the `io_service` doesn't return, the cleanup code is never reached.
Second of all there is only one printf call displayed in the console at most.

And third of all, by doing some debugging I found out that when I quit the program the `handle_stop()` is called once but for some reason the program closes somewhere in the handle (which means sometimes he gets to printf and closes after that and sometimes he just gets to `acceptor_.close()`)

Another thing maybe worth mentioning is that the program doesn't return 0 after close but instead this (the number of threads vary):

```
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1758) has exited with code 2 (0x2).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x17e8) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1034) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The program '[5924] Server.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

So I would like to know why this is happening, how I can fix it and how can I get to the cleanup code properly?

Comment: For clarification, are you calling [`io_service::stop()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stop.html), as is suggested in the question title?  Also, it may be worth posting more code, as the problem looks to be elsewhere.

Comment: Well I had it previously in my handle_stop but 1) it also had no effect (io_service did not return) and 2) I changed it to acceptor_.close() because this was also done in some boost examples. Also what code would you suggest or are you interested in, I'm not sure it would be good if I spam this topic with all of my code ;)

Comment: The server destructors, accept calls, and the handlers may provide some insight.  If `io_service::run()` is not returning, a handler for each `signal_set` is not being called, and the catch is not printing an exception, then it usually indicates that a blocking call is occurring somewhere.

Comment: I updated my post and I actually don't have a custom destructor because I never saw any destructors in the boost examples either.

Answer (score 2):

The `io_service` is never returning because there is always work in the `io_service`.  When [`acceptor::close()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/close/overload1.html) is invoked, the `acceptor`'s asynchronous accept operations  will be cancelled immediately.  The handlers for these cancelled operations will be passed the `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted` error.

In the current code, the problem is the result of a new asynchronous accept operation always being initiated, even if the `acceptor` has been closed.  Thus, work is always being added to the `io_service`.

```
void start_accept(){
  // If the acceptor is closed, handle_accept will be ready to run with an
  // error.
  acceptor_.async_accept(...,  handle_accept);
}

void handle_accept(const system::error_code& error){
  if(!error)
  {
    connection->start();
  }

  // Always starts a new async accept operation, even if the acceptor
  // has closed.
  start_accept();
}
void handle_stop(){
  acceptor_.close();
}
```

The Boost.Asio examples prevents this from occurring checking if `acceptor_` has been closed in the `handle_accept` call.  If the `acceptor_` is no longer open, then the handler returns early without adding more work to the `io_service`.

Here is the relevant snippet from from the [HTTP Server 1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server/server.cpp) example:

```
void server::handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& e)
{
  // Check whether the server was stopped by a signal before this completion
  // handler had a chance to run.
  if (!acceptor_.is_open())
  {
    return;
  }

  if (!e)
  {
    connection_manager_.start(new_connection_);
  }

  start_accept();
}
```

Comment: That sounds good but even after those changes the io_service still doesn't return. When I try to debug whats happening when handle_stop() is called the whole program just quits either after calling acceptor_.close() or printf() (same problem I described above). Just for testing purposes I only used one server object but the problem still occurs, even if nothing happened yet (no clients connected). Oh and the handlers are also not called when calling acceptor_.close() from what I can tell.

Comment: @user2047610: It sounds as though you are invoking undefined behavior in code that is not posted.  Based on the calls, I would suggest verifying that the `TcpConnection` instance is outliving all of the handlers to which it is bound.  Make sure it is publicly inheriting from `enable_shared_from_this<TcpConnection>` and that the instance is bound to handlers with `boost::bind` by `shared_from_this()` instead of `this`.

Comment: But when I do this he throws an exception "tr1::bad_weak_ptr" probably due to use of shared_from_this() in the async call from the signal_set in the constructor of TcpServer, how can I solve that?

Comment: @user2047610: `shared_from_this()` cannot be used in the constructor of the class from which it is being called.  For example, `shared_from_this()` should not be invoked from within `TcpConnection`'s constructor.  Consider reviewing how `shared_from_this()` is used in the HTTP Server 1 [`connection`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server/connection.cpp) class.

Comment: Okay out of curiosity I took the time to compile http example 1 and 3 (took the code 1:1 out of the examples) and the same problem occurs! io_service doesn't return and the same code is returned on exit (-1073741510 (0xc000013a)). This leads me to the question if this might be a deeper problem? I'm working on Windows 7 64bit and use Visual Studio 2010 for compiling and debugging.

Comment: I also did some debugging in the http example 1 and found out that he never even reaches the breakpoint I set in the handle_stop(). Could it be that the win32 console forces a quit once the signal is called or something like that?